# Methods for verifying correct factorisation of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

In an attempt to factor using a GCF, Mia wrote $8x^2 + 4x = 4x(2x – 0)$, which is not correct.

a. Explain how Mia could check her work.

b. What error did Mia make?

She didn't factor using the GFC which is $4x$.

c. Show the correct factorization of $8x^2 + 4x$.

$2^3 x^2 + 2^2 x$

$4(2x^2+x)$

I am not certain that I'm going at this question the right way. Also, how do I go about checking her work?

Comment: A reminder that by visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can learn to type mathematics using $\LaTeX$, making your question more readable and more easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

(a) You can simply plug values for $x$ into the expression and the false factorised expression. For example $x=2$ gives two different results, so the factorised expression is wrong.

(b) Correct.

(c) You can pull out another $x$ to get $$4(2x^2 + x) = 4x(2x + 1)$$
Which is the fully factorised form.

Answer (score 1):

a. Mia could check her work by multiplying out her answer and seeing if she gets the original polynomial back. In her case

$$4x(2x-0)=8x^2-0=8x^2$$

which is wrong.

b. Mia did try to factor out $4x$: she just did it badly. She factored the last term, $+4x$, as $4x\cdot 0$, but it should have been $4x\cdot 1$.

c. The GCF is $4x$, so we get

$$8x^2+4x=4x\cdot 2x+4x\cdot 1=4x(2x+1)$$

In (c) you did not factor out all you could.